# Training Parser in OpenNLP

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, opennlp

I am trying to train OpenNLP parser with special POS tagging; however, there is no documentation available to serve my purpose.

I don't know where should I start. I already train the POS Tagging, and POS Chunker based on documentation in http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker.training.api
But I couldn't find any thing related to my question in the documentation or in the internet. Any help????

Thanks

Comment: What is "special POS tagging"? Nobody can understand what you try to achieve except you. Please be more specific in describing the actual task/problem and/or provide example data. Thus, others will better understand what you try to achieve in training a custom POS model.

Comment: I resolved the issue, but I guess "special POS tagging" is a very generic term and everyone in the machine learning space would know it. Anyways, "special" means related to your own use case.